# Why NameNode is kept in SAFEMODE when it is started?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I came to know that when a *NameNode* is started for few minutes it is under `SAFEMODE` *(which means data can not be written in HDFS)* for few minutes and after sometime automatically it comes to writemode, my question is why `NameNode` is under `SAFEMODE` when it is started

Answer (score 3):

Namenode is started in safemode because it has to reconstruct what the filesystem looked like before it went down. If it does not know how the filesystem looked like, it cannot make any changes to it. 
Remember that the filesystem  in hdfs is essentially the [`fsimage` plus all the entries in the `edit log`](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/03/a-guide-to-checkpointing-in-hadoop/) replayed. It loads the `fsimage` into memory and applies the *edit logs* from the log file. Namenode waits for DataNodes to report their blocks so that it does not prematurely start replicating the blocks. During this time NameNode is in Safemode, i.e. read-only mode. Namenode should automatically leave the Safemode after all DataNodes have completed reporting their blocks.